# htacces rewrite underscore, extension and trailing slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I already got my htaccess set up to remove the php extension and add a trailing slash instead.

Now I need to figure out how I can replace an underscore with a slash inside the same htaccess file, for example:

- Old: `http://localhost/website/parentpage_sub-page.php`
- New: `http://localhost/website/parentpage/sub-page/`

Is there any smart way to do this for multiple urls?

Here's the current htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, if there is any way i could optimize the current htaccess file, i'd be more than glad to hear your advice, as i am rather new to that kind of work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1_$2.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you. It works with the urls i provided, but when i go to "localhost/website/page/" (rewritten from "localhost/website/page.php") i get an error.